# Why do I get an error in the console saying that router is undefined in ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I added this code outside the class because I kept getting different *property* is undefined errors. Now I have this code outside my TypeScript class and added Function before every method and it is working, but I am getting an error that says that router is undefined.

```
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    export class HomeScreenPage implements OnInit {
      constructor(public router: Router ){
       //Checks for inactivity constantly
       this.setupInactivityChecker();
      }
    }

function startTimer() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 2000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    goActive();
}

function goInactive() {
  var router : Router;
    // do something
     console.log('Ahhhh.. finally inactive again. Now I may rest -_-');
     router.navigate(['login']);
}

function goActive() {
    // do something
    console.log('Active again');
    startTimer();
}

function setupInactivityChecker() {
  addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, true);

  startTimer();
}
```

If I call the methods inside the class as such:

```
export class HomeScreenPage implements OnInit {
    constructor(public router: Router ){
        //Checks for inactivity constantly
        this.setupInactivityChecker();
    }

startTimer() {
timeoutID = window.setTimeout(this.goInactive, 2000);
}

resetTimer(e) {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  this.goActive;
}

goInactive() {
  // do something
   console.log('Ahhhh.. finally inactive again. Now I may rest -_-');
   this.router.navigate(['login']);
}

goActive() {
  // do something
  console.log('Active again');
  this.startTimer;
}

setupInactivityChecker() {
addEventListener("mousemove", this.resetTimer, true);
addEventListener("mousedown", this.resetTimer, true);
addEventListener("keypress", this.resetTimer, true);
addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", this.resetTimer, true);
addEventListener("mousewheel", this.resetTimer, true);
addEventListener("touchmove", this.resetTimer, true);
addEventListener("MSPointerMove", this.resetTimer, true);

this.startTimer;
}
}
```

I get an error saying that goActive isn't a function in the console

Comment: initialized it in your `constructor(private router :Router ){}` and the use it like `this.router.navigate(['/login'])`

Answer (score 0):

You must inject router in your constructor first, like

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';   

export class componentName {
constructor(private router: Router){}
 goInactive() {
   console.log('Ahhhh.. finally inactive again. Now I may rest -_-');
   this.router.navigate(['login']);
 }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean `goInactive()` instead of `function goInactive()`? You've got the right idea but invalid syntax.

Comment: When I implement these new functions inside the class and remove the 'function' identifier then there are no errors but the console warns me that goActive() isn't a function. I will update my code more completely to give you guys a better idea. @EmadAbdou

Comment: @Emad the functions I need are outside of my class

Comment: yeah @AluanHaddad its `goInactive()` i will edit my answer, Thanks

Comment: @JeandrePretørius put all your functions inside the class, and you should call `goActive()` function like this ` this.goActive() `